# UISearchBar Scope Bar Position?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I am here on an iPad Application and i would like to know if its possible to move the Scope Bar from right to my UISearchBar to another position?

[image]

I would like to have my Scope Bar under my Search Bar. Is that possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here with the same problem, very interested, and no solution by now

Comment: Here is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33390408/positioning-of-scope-bar-in-uisearchcontroller

Comment: Ive done this by creating my "own" segmented control, and implemented the same functionality like an scope bar!

Comment: would you provide some code? Also, you can answer your own question, I'll upvote it if I can reproduce your solution

Comment: Done, hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok this is my solution for that. Ill implemented my own segmented control to create a possibility for a search scope.

```
    let categories = ["Scope1", "Scope2", "Scope3"]
    segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: "changeScope:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged) 
    segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(8, 5, 800, 30)
    segmentedControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    segmentedControl.tintColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()

    // add it in a scrollView, because ill got too much categories here. Just if you need that:

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(segmentedControl.frame.size.width + 16, segmentedControl.frame.size.height-1)
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false;
    // set first category
    segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
    scrollView.addSubview(segmentedControl)
```

Here is the function for the scope bar, do wantever you want when a user switches a scope:

```
func changeScope(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    switch(sender.selectedSegmentIndex) { 
    }
 }
```

In my case, ill got several resultArrays from an Webservice, and ill only show the selected result (normally ill Add them to 1 huge resultSet)

Hope that helps maybe someone else.

Comment: I've created a somewhat inspired version of that, so... thanks! :)