# Positioning of scope bar in UISearchController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I'm developing a iPad-only app, and I've got a UITableView inside a UIViewController. I setted a **UISearchController** as the header of the UITableView. This search control has three scopes. I want the scope selector to be **below the search bar**. With the following piece of code, I'm able to get it at init, but when I start with the input, the selector goes to the right, **and remains there**.

Here is an animation:

[image: F***ing scope selector]

And here is the relevant code:

```
self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;    

self.searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = @[@"Uno",@"Dos", @"Tres"];
self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
self.searchController.searchBar.showsScopeBar = YES;
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;

[self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've also incorporated a UISearchController inside my app. I'm using Xcode 7.1.

I had the same problem and simply removed "self.searchController.searchBar.showsScopeBar" from my code.

Either change the value to false or remove it completely.

self.searchController.searchBar.showsScopeBar = false

Comment: not worked for me, sorry... the problem persists. Thanks anyway

Comment: I finished doing a custom-made component, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26295330/uisearchbar-scope-bar-position)

Comment: I'm accepting your answer since you're the only one who do it

Answer (score 1):

Here's something interesting I read from apple:

> When a search bar is present, a scope bar can appear near it. The
>   scope bar displays below the search bar, regardless of orientation,
>   unless you use a search display controller in your code (for more
>   information on the way this works, see UISearchDisplayController Class
>   Reference). When you use a search display controller, the scope bar is
>   displayed within the search bar to the right of the search field when
>   the device is in landscape orientation (in portrait orientation, it’s
>   below the search bar).

So what worked for me was using only a UISearchBar instead of the whole UISearchDisplayController.